# TypeScript: Convert array of strings to its elements

Tags: typescript

Say I have an array `const arr = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']`. How do I make a type like

```
type Test = { str: Items<arr> }
```

so that `Test` types have a `str` attribute that is either `'key1', 'key2', 'key3'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default TypeScript will infer `arr` type as `string[]`. If we want to infer it as `['key1', 'key2', 'key3']` we can either do `as const` or `as ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']`

To get union type of object values you need to pass a union of object indices as a type index. `type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]`. But in this case we have an array so just `[number]` will do.

```
const arr = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'] as const;

type Test = { str: typeof arr[number] }

const test: Test = {
  str: 'key1'
}
```

[TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gcgNYFMCeAjJgDQw4EBMp5e+AzJgLrwQyiRQDcAUD1PgAOuGABVc0VDADeMaAgBcMAcJAAzeEnRgArgFsARrgQsAvnw6SoEqEvGS00njDlRFtAsR6mgA)

Comment: I thought this would work but vscode shows `str`'s type as `(property) str: string` instead of the expected `'key1' | 'key2' | 'key3'`

Comment: Did you add `as const` or `as ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']` at the end of the `arr` definition?

Comment: You're right, what's `as const` mean here?

Comment: `as const` is a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) which tells TypeScript to treat this variable as a readonly constant. In case of readonly constant TypeScript can safely infer the type as literal `['key1', 'key2', 'key3']` because assertion guarantees that the array will not be mutated later in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Define a type for just the values of str property separately. Then use it when defining your custom type `Type`.

Something like the following:

```
type Str = 'key1' | 'key2' | 'key3';
type Type = { str: Str }
```

Comment: I think this is the ideal solution and type `arr: Str[]` instead. Won't mark as answer since it technically doesn't answer the question. Thanks tho!

Comment: I doubt this doesn't answer your question except if you didn't properly convey what you wanted to achieve. You want `Test` types to have an str attribute that is of either of those 3 values. This means `Test` types, technically, are objects with the str field. (they can have other fields). And if the value of the str attribute is either of those 3 values, the taking the type `Str` is enough, and not the type `Str[]` because `Str[]` will require an array. do you understand?